# Fabricators failing with mongoid from validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, mongodb, mongoid

I can't get my any test to run because every user I try to fabricate generates validation errors.

I have the following test.

```
class BillTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase

  def setup
    load_all_sponsors
    @the_bill = Bill.new(:govtrack_name => "h1")
    @user1 = Fabricate(:user1)
    @user2 = Fabricate(:user2)
```

My fabrications are defined by:

```
Fabricator(:user) do
   email      'another_user_here@domain.com'
   name       'anew user'
   roles_mask 1
   password   "secret"
   password_confirmation "secret"
   polco_groups {[Fabricate(:polco_group, :name => 'foreign', :type => :custom)]}
end

Fabricator(:admin, :class_name => :user) do
  email 'admin@yourdomain.com'
  name  'Administrator'
  roles_mask  5
  password   "secret"
  password_confirmation "secret"
end

Fabricator(:registered, :class_name => :user) do
   email      'registered_user@domain.com'
   name       'Tim TheRegistered'
   roles_mask 2
   password   "the_secret"
   password_confirmation "the_secret"
   polco_groups {[Fabricate(:polco_group, {:name => 'AL', :type => :state}),
              Fabricate(:polco_group, {:name => 'AL01', :type => :district}),
              Fabricate(:polco_group, {:name => "Kirk\'s Kids" , :type => :custom})]}
end

Fabricator(:user1, :class_name => :user) do
   email      'user1@domain.com'
   name       'User1'
   roles_mask 2
   password   "the_big_secret"
   password_confirmation "the_big_secret"
   polco_groups {[Fabricate(:polco_group, {:name => 'AL', :type => :state}),
              Fabricate(:polco_group, {:name => 'AL01', :type => :district}),
              Fabricate(:polco_group, {:name => "Kirk\'s Kids" , :type => :custom})]}
end

Fabricator(:user2, :class_name => :user) do
   email      'user2@domain.com'
   name       'User2'
   roles_mask 2
   password   "the_big_secret"
   password_confirmation "the_big_secret"
   polco_groups {[Fabricate(:polco_group, {:name => 'AL', :type => :state}),
              Fabricate(:polco_group, {:name => 'FL01', :type => :district}),
              Fabricate(:polco_group, {:name => "Ft. Sam Washington 1st Grade" , :type => :custom})]}
end
```

No matter which test runs, I get the same error

```
  9) Error:
test_update_from_directory(BillTest):
Mongoid::Errors::Validations: Validation failed - Email is already taken, Email is already taken, Name is already taken.
    test/unit/bill_test.rb:8:in `setup'
```

I have tried a number of different fabricators, inheriting in all kinds of different ways and nothing gets past this error. I'm pretty desperate for help on this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be user the "ffaker" gem to generate email addresses and the like in your specs. Also, you should be inheriting fields form previously defined fabricators, as illustrated below.

```
Fabricator(:user) do
 email      { Faker::Internet.email }
 name       { Faker::Name.name }
 roles_mask 1
 password   "secret"
 password_confirmation "secret"
 polco_groups {[Fabricate(:polco_group, :name => 'foreign', :type => :custom)]}
end

Fabricator(:admin, :from => :user) do
  roles_mask  5
end

Fabricator(:registered, :from => :user) do
  roles_mask 2
  polco_groups {[Fabricate(:polco_group, :name => 'AL', :type => :state),
          Fabricate(:polco_group, :name => 'AL01', :type => :district),
          Fabricate(:polco_group, :name => "Kirk\'s Kids" , :type => :custom)]}
end

Fabricator(:user1, :from => :registered)

Fabricator(:user2, :from => :registered) do
  polco_groups {[Fabricate(:polco_group, {:name => 'AL', :type => :state}),
          Fabricate(:polco_group, {:name => 'FL01', :type => :district}),
          Fabricate(:polco_group, {:name => "Ft. Sam Washington 1st Grade" , :type => :custom})]}
end
```

It is unrelated to your issue, but it looks like user1 and user2 should just be calls to Fabricate and not actually defined as Fabricators. I don't recommend putting that much explicit information in the Fabricator. You should only be defining was is necessary to generate a valid object. Any specific data should be in the service of a particular spec.

Answer (score 0):

After running in to Machinist and Fabricator issues with Mongoid I've settled on FactoryGirl - the syntax feels like a step back - but it works.

The issues I had with the others were related to validation, STI and polymorphism.

Comment: i didn't know that FactoryGirl worked with Mongoid. I was having problems with Mongoid and FactoryGirl which forced my move to Fabrications.

Comment: It doesn't fully. For basic objects, I use FactoryGirl. But FactoryGirl doesn't support anything that contains an array or hash, so I use Fabrications. No reason we can't use both.